# How can I embed a hyperlink within an accordion style web part...?

Tags: web-part, 2016, accordion

I created a hyperlink accordion that will be used for a FAQs section of a webpage. I got it working but I need to have a hyperlink within the text of the accordion. Also, I can't seem to modify the web part once I embed my code onto the page..? I want to edit the text color, size, etc. Lastly, I spent hours trying to get the first dropdown to not display when a user navigates to the page...I want them all hidden unless someone clicks it

Below is an image of my webpart:

[image: Image of the webpart]

My code is below:

Sorry, for some reason when I paste my html code, it's being run and only showing output and note code so this was the only way I could paste it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>What’s the City’s living Wage?</h3>
  <div>
    <p> Living Wage On November 10, 2015 City Council passed Resolution 15-2141 which requires prime contractors, awarded general service contracts valued greater than $50,000, and first-tier subcontractors on the contract to pay their employees rendering services on the contract no less than the “living wage” rate. The current living wage rate is $11.71..</p>
  </div>
  <h3>What is Bonfire?</h3>
  <div>
    <p> Bonfire is our solicitation portal. It is where the City of Dallas posts bid and solicitation opportunities. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>How do I reset my password?</h3>
  <div>
    <p> For instructions to reset your Bonfire password click here. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3> For instructions to fill out an online bid table, click here:</h3>
  <div>
    <p> For instructions to fill out an online bid table, click here </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You don't mention, but I assume this is in a Content Edit WebPart (CEWP)?

Comment: Yes, it's SharePoint web content edit Webpart. Can I tried including my link in the html code above but it did only displays the url webpage......

Comment: Where do you need a hyperlink?  You should be able to put anchor elements `<a>` in any of those inner `<div>`s.

Comment: I've added another pic to hopefully see which sharepoint web I'm using (2016). When I go into insert, the option for link is greyed out?

Comment: I need the link within the answer to the question. Once a user clicks the accordion question, I need the hyperlink within the text below it

Comment: Also, with a complex CEWP, it is better to maintain your code in a separate file in a library, then use the link attribute of the webpart to connect it, rather than having to edit the page and the webpart to tweak the html.

Comment: I did try that and uploading a .JS file with the code and using a content list but it had issues when loading it onto the page..

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't think I'm familiar with link attributes. Might be a better solution as well since I also want to edit the text size and color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only including a snippet of code for brevity, but if I am understanding you correctly, putting a link in your first answer would look something like this:

```
<h3>What’s the City’s living Wage?</h3>  <div>   
     <p> Living Wage On November 10, 2015 City Council passed Resolution   
             <a href="https://www.google.com">here is a link to Google in the middle of an answer</a>   
           15-2141 which requires prime contractors, awarded general service contracts valued greater than $50,000, and first-tier subcontractors on the contract to pay their employees rendering services on the contract no less than the “living wage” rate. The current living wage rate is $11.71..</p>  
</div>
```

For more details on using the anchor `<a>` tag, see the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

For more info on using a separate HTML file linked to the webpart, see [this guide](https://www.uwsp.edu/infotech/web/Pages/link-custom-code-content-editor.aspx).

Comment: and I'm assuming I can modify the url to display as a hyperlink text...?Also, anyway to adjust the text color/size? Sorry, I'm new to SharePoint lol

Comment: Yes, I added a link to the answer to see more details on using the anchor tag.  I also added a link to linking the webpart to an HTML file that you can edit separately from the page.

Comment: you're a life saver Willman thank you! :)